# Why App won't install in Android emulator automatically

Tags: android, eclipse

I followed the tutorial on http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

After I pressed run, the emulator show up and display the home menu for one to unlock. But the Hello Android app won't install.

I googled and tried many suggestion on the web and most of them failed. I feel hopeless. The only way to make it work is to launch the emulator and kill the adb.exe, after the adb.exe was revived, it will install the app. However, it doesn't work everytime.

Is this a bug? Does any know the cause? If the eclipse is something optional such as Eclipse, I can just switch another one...

Here is some of my configuration:

```
- Windows Xp
- Android SDK r19 on D:\
- ADT v18
- Eclipse in C:\
- Workspace in D:\
```

Comment: This may sound stupid, but be sure to try restarting your computer. Sometimes adb and Eclipse start acting weird (requiring adb restarts, Eclipse restarts, apps not publishing, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to download a fresh eclipse and install again the ADT-Plugin for eclipse. I guess there is a problem in your previous install.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Restart Your Computer
2. run

   adb uninstall your.package
3. Start Eclipse and run the application
4. Unlock the emulator

Comment: how do you unlock the emulator?